# Visualization of sorting algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, qt

I recently started to learn Qt framework and decided to create an app to visualize the sorting algorithms(for this moment there are 5 sorting algorithms). I just want to know if I'm doing everything correctly. Here is a code of visualization function where all of the processes takes place. The visualization class is connected with a signals from "algorithm" class to know about columns swaps, sorts done and array accesses. (65 lines of code)

```
    #ifndef WIDGET_H
    #define WIDGET_H

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QtWidgets>

    #include "algorithms.h"

    namespace Ui {
    class Widget;
    }

    class Thread;

    class Widget : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~Widget();

    private slots:
        void on_sortButton_clicked();
        void on_algorithmSelection_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*);
        void on_amountChanger_valueChanged(int);
        void on_delayChanger_valueChanged(int);

        void on_comparision(int, int);
        void sortButtonStatus(int);
        void sortDone(int);
        void resetColumns(int, int);

    private:
        Ui::Widget *ui;
        Thread *mThread;
        QGraphicsScene *scene;

        //setting up columns, shuffeling them
        void columnsSetUp(int, int);
        void threadUpdate(int, int);

        std::vector<QGraphicsRectItem*> columns;
        std::vector<double> columnsHeight;

        QMap<int, QString> AlgorithmList;

        //delay of sorting in ms
        int sortDelay;

        double columnsWidth;
        double sceneHeight;
        double sceneWidth;

        int amountOfColumns;
        int comparisions;

        //key which is use to establish the algorithm to sort columns
        int algorithmKey;

        // (-1) - App started, 0 - App ready to sort, (1) - App sorting, (2) - App sorted
        int appStates;
    };

    #endif // WIDGET_H
```

visualization.cpp (235 lines of code)

```
    #include "includes/visualization.h"
    #include "ui_widget.h"

    #include <random>
    #include <algorithm>

    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        //setting up scene
        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        ui->cellsToSortBackground->setScene(scene);
        ui->cellsToSortBackground->verticalScrollBar()->blockSignals(true);
        ui->cellsToSortBackground->horizontalScrollBar()->blockSignals(true);

        //configuring variables
        appStates = -1; // (-1) - App started

        sceneHeight = ui->cellsToSortBackground->size().height();
        sceneWidth = ui->cellsToSortBackground->size().width();
        comparisions = 0;

        //customize the ListWidget & set a QMap for sorting algorithms
        for(int i = 0; i < ui->algorithmSelection->count(); i++)
        {
          QListWidgetItem *item = ui->algorithmSelection->item(i);
          item->setSizeHint(QSize(item->sizeHint().width(), 50));
          AlgorithmList.insert(i, item->text());
        }

        //to improve UX
        ui->amountChanger->setDisabled(true);
        ui->delayChanger->setDisabled(true);
        ui->sortButton->setDisabled(true);

        //creating 100 columns with sorting delay == 1ms , setting them up
        columnsSetUp(1, 100);
    }

    void Widget::columnsSetUp(int ms, int n)
    {
        //configuring variables
        ui->LabelComparisions_var->setNum(0);
        ui->LabelArrayAccesses_var->setNum(0);

        sortDelay = ms;
        amountOfColumns = n;
        columnsWidth = sceneWidth / amountOfColumns;

        //setting up columns to sort
        columns.resize(static_cast<unsigned>(amountOfColumns));

        //setting up columns height
        double incrementBy = sceneHeight / amountOfColumns;
        for(auto i = incrementBy; i <= sceneHeight; i += incrementBy)
            columnsHeight.push_back(i);

        //randomize an array
        std::random_device m_random;
        std::mt19937 e_random(m_random());
        std::shuffle(columnsHeight.begin(), columnsHeight.end(), e_random);

        //aplying columns to scene
        auto j = 0;
        auto k = 0.0;
        for(auto &p : columns)
        {
            p = new QGraphicsRectItem;
            p->setRect(k, (sceneHeight - columnsHeight[j]), columnsWidth , columnsHeight[j]);
            p->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 68, 255)));

            if(amountOfColumns <= 200)
                p->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
            else if(amountOfColumns > 200 && amountOfColumns <= 300)
                p->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 1));
            else
                p->setPen(Qt::NoPen);

            scene->addItem(p);

            j++;
            k += columnsWidth;
        }
    }

    void Widget::resetColumns(int ms, int n)
    {
        for(auto &p : columns)
            scene->removeItem(p);

        columnsHeight.clear();

        columnsSetUp(ms, n);
        threadUpdate(sortDelay, algorithmKey);
    }

    void Widget::threadUpdate(int ms, int key)
    {
        mThread = new Thread(ms, key, static_cast<int>(amountOfColumns), columnsHeight, this);

        connect(mThread, SIGNAL(comparision(int, int)), this, SLOT(on_comparision(int, int)));
        connect(mThread, SIGNAL(sortDone(int)), this, SLOT(sortDone(int)));
        connect(mThread, SIGNAL(arrayAccess(int)), ui->LabelArrayAccesses_var, SLOT(setNum(int)));
        connect(mThread, SIGNAL(changeButtonStatus(int)), this, SLOT(sortButtonStatus(int)));
    }

    void Widget::on_algorithmSelection_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
    {
        if(appStates == -1)
        {
            ui->sortButton->setEnabled(true);
            ui->amountChanger->setEnabled(true);
            ui->delayChanger->setEnabled(true);

            appStates = 0;
            sortButtonStatus(appStates);
        }

        if(appStates == 0)
        {
            algorithmKey = AlgorithmList.key(item->text());
            ui->LabelSortingWith_var->setText(item->text());
        }
    }

    void Widget::on_amountChanger_valueChanged(int n)
    {
        if(appStates == 0)
            resetColumns(sortDelay, n);
    }

    void Widget::on_delayChanger_valueChanged(int ms)
    {
        if(appStates == 0)
            resetColumns(ms, static_cast<int>(amountOfColumns));
    }


    void Widget::on_sortButton_clicked()
    {
        switch(appStates)
        {
            case 0:
                sortButtonStatus(1);
                comparisions = 0;
                threadUpdate(sortDelay, algorithmKey);
                mThread->start();
                break;

            case 1:
                mThread->terminate();
                sortButtonStatus(2);
                break;

            case 2:
                for(auto &p : columns)
                    scene->removeItem(p);

                columnsHeight.clear();
                columnsSetUp(sortDelay, static_cast<int>(amountOfColumns));
                sortButtonStatus(0);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void Widget::sortButtonStatus(int state)
    {
        QString buttonText;
        QString style;

        switch(state)
        {
        case 0:
            buttonText = "sort";
            ui->amountChanger->setEnabled(true);
            ui->delayChanger->setEnabled(true);
            ui->algorithmSelection->setEnabled(true);
            style = "background-color: rgba(255, 0, 68, 255); color: #fff";
            break;

        case 1:
            buttonText = "cancel";
            ui->amountChanger->setDisabled(true);
            ui->delayChanger->setDisabled(true);
            ui->algorithmSelection->setDisabled(true);
            style = "background-color: #000; color: #fff";
            break;

        case 2:
            buttonText = "new sort";
            ui->sortButton->setEnabled(true);
            style = "background-color: rgb(85, 0, 255); color: #fff";
            break;
        }

        appStates = state;
        ui->sortButton->setText(buttonText);
        ui->sortButton->setStyleSheet(style);
    }

    void Widget::on_comparision(int n, int k)
    {
        auto nRect = columns[n]->rect();
        auto kRect = columns[k]->rect();
        auto nColumnPos = nRect.left();
        auto kColumnPos = kRect.left();

        nRect.moveLeft(kColumnPos);
        kRect.moveLeft(nColumnPos);

        columns[n]->setRect(nRect);
        columns[k]->setRect(kRect);

        std::swap(columns[n], columns[k]);

        comparisions++;
        ui->LabelComparisions_var->setNum(comparisions);
    }

    void Widget::sortDone(int n)
    {
        columns[n]->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0,200,0)));
    }

    Widget::~Widget()
    {
        mThread->terminate();
        delete ui;
    }
```

That's how algorithms class looks like(with only Bubble Sort implemented for example) (47 lines of code):

```
    #ifndef THREAD_H
    #define THREAD_H

    #include <QThread>
    #include <QtWidgets>

    class Thread : public QThread
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Thread(int, int, int, std::vector<double>, QObject*);

    signals:
        void comparision(int, int);
        void sortDone(int);
        void arrayAccess(int);
        void changeButtonStatus(int);

    protected:
        void run() override;

    private:
        std::vector<double> columnsHeight;
        int sortDoneDelay;
        int sortDelay;
        int amount;
        int sortWith;
        int arrayAccessVariable;

        void swap(int, int);
        void isAccessToArray();
        void Sorted();

        //sorting algorithms declaration
        void BubbleSort();

        /*
        void RecursiveBubbleSort(int);
        void CocktailSort();
        void GnomeSort();

        int QuickSortPartition(int, int);
        void QuickSort(int, int);

        void Heapify(int n, int i);
        void HeapSort();
        */
    };

    #endif // THREAD_H
```

Wonder if QThreading is done correctly, I had a lot of problems with that. (63 lines of code)

```
    #include "includes/algorithms.h"

    Thread::Thread(int ms, int alg, int n, std::vector<double> col, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QThread(parent)
    {
        sortWith = alg;
        amount = n;
        columnsHeight = col;
        arrayAccessVariable = 0;

        sortDoneDelay = (amount >= 300 ? 2 : 5);
        sortDelay = ms;
    }

    void Thread::run()
    {
        switch(sortWith)
        {
            case 0: BubbleSort(); break;
            /*
            case 1: RecursiveBubbleSort(amount); break;
            case 2: CocktailSort(); break;
            case 3: GnomeSort(); break;
            case 4: QuickSort(0, amount -1); break;
            case 5: HeapSort(); break;
            */
        }
        Sorted();
    }

    void Thread::Sorted()
    {
        for(auto i=0; i<amount; i++)
        {
            emit sortDone(i);
            msleep(sortDoneDelay);
        }
        emit changeButtonStatus(2);
    }

    void Thread::swap(int n, int k)
    {
        std::swap(columnsHeight[n], columnsHeight[k]);
        emit comparision(n, k);
    }

    void Thread::isAccessToArray()
    {
        arrayAccessVariable++;
        emit arrayAccess(arrayAccessVariable);
    }

    //--------- BUBBLE SORT -----------

    void Thread::BubbleSort()
    {
        for(auto i = 0; i < amount; i++)
                for(auto j = 0; j< amount-1; j++)
                {
                    if(columnsHeight[j] > columnsHeight[j+1])
                        swap(j, j+1);

                    isAccessToArray();
                    msleep(sortDelay);
                }
    }

    //implementations of recursive bubble sort, cocktail sort, gnome sort, quick sort, heap sort are deleted for this example.
```

An app preview video is available on my github's project page in README file.

https://github.com/letelete/Visualization_Of_Sorting_Algorithms/blob/master/README.md

Each opinion/review will be appreciated.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Does it work as expected, we can only review working code here.

Comment: Yes it does, but I paste there only 2 classes, to run this app You need main.cpp, .pro file and .ui file. I also erase 5 algorithms and left only Bubble Sort to show You an example.  You can go to my gist for the rest of the code. https://github.com/letelete/Visualization_Of_Sorting_Algorithms